# Building a lambda with an Expression Tree

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, expression-trees

I'm having a hard time grasping the expression trees. I would like to be able to build an expression tree manually for the following statement:

```
c => c.Property
```

A lot of the tutorials focus around comparing, while I just want it to return this one property. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourClass), "c");
Expression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Property");
Expression<Func<YourClass, PropertyType>> lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<YourClass, PropertyType>>(property, parameter);
```